# IIS7.5 not displaying Flash object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I'm writing a MVC web app in ASP.NET MVC, which is supposed to be serving up a Flash object written by one of my colleagues.  I don't know any Flash; he doesn't know any C#/ASP.NET; hence the question goes to SO!

The code on my web page looks like this:

```
<head>
(blah blah blah...)
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/FlashStuff/js/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var GP_MLM_flashvars = {};
    GP_MLM_flashvars.remote = 'true';
    GP_MLM_flashvars.streamprovider = 'localweb';
    GP_MLM_flashvars.referer = '';
    GP_MLM_flashvars.bgcolor = '#000033';
    var GP_MLM_params = {};
    GP_MLM_params.menu = 'false';
    GP_MLM_params.allowFullScreen = 'true';
    GP_MLM_params.salign = 'tl';
    GP_MLM_params.scale = 'noscale';
    GP_MLM_params.wmode = 'opaque';
    GP_MLM_params.bgcolor = '#000033';
    var GP_MLM_attributes = {};
    GP_MLM_attributes.id = 'GP_MLM';
    GP_MLM_attributes.name = 'GP_MLM';
    swfobject.embedSWF('/FlashStuff/swf/GP_MLM.swf', 'GP_MLM', '100%', '100%', '9', '/FlashStuff/expressInstall.swf', GP_MLM_flashvars, GP_MLM_params, GP_MLM_attributes);          
  </script>
</head>
(etc.)
```

When I debug this page using the VS Development Server, it all appears very happily and works fine.  But if I try to debug using my local IIS (7.5) server, the Flash object doesn't get loaded.

I'm guessing I need to do something on IIS to enable using the Flash object - but what?

**EDIT:** Problem partially solved; the clue came from the "404" error (thanks @Beliskner).

It appears that when you're running under the VS Development Server, your root folder is the project folder, and in my case "/FlashStuff" comes directly off my project folder, so that worked fine.

But when you run off the IIS server, the root folder is the Default Web Site (or whatever site you're using).  Now, with a project URL set to "http://localhost/MyTestApp", I have to prefix all my paths with "/MyTestApp", e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyTestApp/FlashStuff/js/swfobject.js"></script>
```

Changed all the paths; works fine now.

This is a pretty ugly situation now, though - because I am now hard coding deployment-specific information into my app!  So if I decide to deploy my app onto an IIS server in a folder called "MyLiveApp", I have to go around changing the file references **everywhere**! And if I want to debug it - then what?  Go changing all the references back to "MyTestApp"?

Obviously I'm not the first developer to come up against this situation, and it is unthinkable that you have to do what I'm saying above.  So what is the trick for dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you setup the IIS MIME types? Have you used firefox firebug to check the request isn't 404ing?

**Mime types**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx - I suggest using the GUI

Extension: ".swf"

Type is: "application/x-shockwave-flash"

**Firebug**

Firebug network monitor: http://getfirebug.com/network

**Edit**
Use this to solve your problem: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/the_script_tag_runatserver_problem_solution_using_resolveurl.aspx

Comment: Uhh... I guess the answer is "No", because I haven't the foggiest idea what you're talking about!  :D

Comment: OK, I more or less worked out what you mean.  In answer to your first question: I didn't set anything up in the MIME Types; but I see that ".swf" is listed already as "application/x-shockwave-flash".  As to the 2nd question: by using Charles it appears that the call to "swfobject.js" is "404ing", if by that you mean that the response is a 404.0 error.  Now why would it do that, if the .js file is in the correct folder - and why would it make a diff whether I'm using IIS or VS debugger?

Comment: Hmm, try following the path to swfobject.js that is shown it firebug but locally from the root of your application to see if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding the Flash object in the body of your html page

```
<head> (blah blah blah...)
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/FlashStuff/js/swfobject.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var GP_MLM_flashvars = {};
    GP_MLM_flashvars.remote = 'true';
    GP_MLM_flashvars.streamprovider = 'localweb';
    GP_MLM_flashvars.referer = '';
    GP_MLM_flashvars.bgcolor = '#000033';
    var GP_MLM_params = {};
    GP_MLM_params.menu = 'false';
    GP_MLM_params.allowFullScreen = 'true';
    GP_MLM_params.salign = 'tl';
    GP_MLM_params.scale = 'noscale';
    GP_MLM_params.wmode = 'opaque';
    GP_MLM_params.bgcolor = '#000033';
    var GP_MLM_attributes = {};
    GP_MLM_attributes.id = 'GP_MLM';
    GP_MLM_attributes.name = 'GP_MLM';
    swfobject.embedSWF('/FlashStuff/swf/GP_MLM.swf', 'GP_MLM', '100%', '100%', '9', '/FlashStuff/expressInstall.swf', GP_MLM_flashvars, GP_MLM_params, GP_MLM_attributes);             
 </script>

(etc.)
</body>
```

I guess embedSWF is a javascript function to write out the `object` tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add swf as a IIS 7 mime type per site.
I had this same issue with .mp4 files