# asp.net specific embedded flash file doesn't work on the server

Tags: asp.net, flash, iis-7

I want to show a flash file on my site. I use next code to embed flash into web page:

```
<object height="344" width="425">
  <embed src="/flash/1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="344" width="425">
</object>
```

All works fine locally.
[image]

But when I load this page on the web server (IIS 7.0) flash loads but does't work (in all browsers).

[image]

Also I know that only this particular flash file doesn't work. Others flash files work fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: If it works at all in any browser, then this isn't an IIS issue (mime type is the only thing I can think of on the IIS side). What version of the player is in the browser that "doesn't work" - at the end of the day, this is likely a Flash/player issue (or embed code)

Comment: I agree with EdSF.  If at least one browser is able to show it correctly then it has to be a mime-type setting issue on the server that one or more browsers is correcting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS7.5 not displaying Flash object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795331/iis7-5-not-displaying-flash-object)

Comment: All browsers don't show this flash. I thought about mime types but others flashes load correctly. Can this .swf file be not of type "application/x-shockwave-flash"?